# Filter values from Java stream on condition that a value is null

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to get values out of a stream if they meet a certain criteria OR if a certain value is null:

```
for (ProjectTask task : tasks) {
   TaskEnrollmentUpdateRequest updateTask = updatedPhase.getTasks().stream()
        .filter(t -> task.getId().equals(t.getId()) || t.getId() == null).findFirst().get();
    if (updateTask != null) {
      if (updateTask.getId() != null) {
        mapper.map(updateTask, task);
      } else {
        TaskEnrollmentUpdateRequest ted = updateTask;
      }
    }
...
}
```

The idea is that I will update `task` with the values in `updateTask` if `updateTask` already exists in the `tasks` array i.e. its id value is present on an object in that array. If the id is null, which it will be if this a new task, then I want to create a new task to add to the `tasks` array. Problem is my filter function is filtering out all values that have a null Id so I can never add them to the `tasks` array.

Is this the correct function to filter out the values as I have described above?:

```
t -> task.getId().equals(t.getId()) || t.getId() == null
```

Comment: Yes. But updateTask can't possibly be null, since Optional.get() never returns null.

Comment: Isn’t an `updateTask` with `task.getId().equals(t.getId())` preferable over one with `t.getId() == null`? And what’s the purpose of `TaskEnrollmentUpdateRequest ted = updateTask;`? That assignment has no effect. Generally, you should rethink the logic. You don’t want to have a loop performing another linear search for matching ids for each element…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following along from what @JBNizet says, I think you want something like this:

```
for (ProjectTask task : tasks) {
    Optional<TaskEnrollmentUpdateRequest> updateTaskOptional = updatedPhase.getTasks().stream()
            .filter(t -> task.getId().equals(t.getId()) || t.getId() == null).findFirst();
    if (updateTaskOptional.isPresent()) {
        TaskEnrollmentUpdateRequest updateTask = updateTaskOptional.get();
        if (updateTask.getId() != null) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If your filter results in an empty List, then `.findFirst()` will return an empty `Optional`, and calling `.get()` on it will throw an exception since it has no value.  So you have to check for that case specifically by checking if the `Optional` returned by `.findFirst()` contains a value rather than assuming that it always will.

Comment: My taste would be for using `updateTaskOptional.ifPresent()` (`f` instead of `s` in the method name).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
tasks.stream()
        .flatMap(task -> updatedPhase.getTasks().stream().map(ut -> Map.entry(task, ut)))
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().getId() == null || e.getKey().getId().equals(e.getValue().getId()))
        .findFirst().ifPresent(e -> {
            if (e.getValue().getId() != null) {
                mapper.map(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
            } else {
                TaskEnrollmentUpdateRequest ted = e.getValue();
            }
        });
```